# Dynamic resizing of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I have a class with items pointing to an Airport object. The size of the dynamic array starts off at 10. When `total` is greater than the size of the array and I have read in data to fill up the array, I need to double the size of the array, copy the elements from the old array into the newly sized array and then delete the old array. The array will continue to read in data, then resize, and continue this until all the data from the file is read into the `items` array.

There are no errors that occur, but the problem is when I run the program, it crashes. I think my `doubleSize` function to resize the array might be the cause of this. Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
class AirportList
{
private:
   Airport* items;
   int total;
   int maxElements;
   int oldAmount;
public:
     AirportList()
     {
        oldAmount = 10;
        maxElements = 10;
        items = new Aiport[maxElements];
        // a file was opened to read in data before this, 
        // total equals the total amount of lines in the file
        string cppstr;
     for (int counter = 0; counter < total; counter++)
     {
        getline(infile, cppstr);
        items[counter] = Airport(cppstr);   // the Airport constructor                       
                                            // parses each line to read in   
                                           //  the data and sets each Airport
                                           //  object into the items array
        if (total > maxElements && counter == maxElements)
            doubleSize(items, maxElements, oldAmount);
     }
        infile.close();
     }

     void doubleSize(Airport*& orig, int maxElements, int oldAmount)
     {
        maxElements = maxElements * 2;
        Aiport* resized = new Aiport[maxElements];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldAmount; i++)
            resized[i] = orig[i];
        delete [] orig;
        orig = resized;
        oldAmount = maxElements;
     }

};
```

Comment: ` I think my doubleSize function to resize the array might be the cause of this` Well debug it and confirm that is the case! First obvious question: is the `oldAmount` parameter to `doubleSize` supposed to be a reference? If not then setting it on the last line does nothing. (ditto for `maxElements`. I think that HAS to be a ref, `oldAmount` not so important.

Comment: @John3136 I tried debugging it, but I am still new to debugging, so I couldn't find out what's causing the crash unfortunately.

Comment: You can debug just by printing out values to see how far your program gets and what is it's state at different points.

Comment: The code isn't correct. You must declare the array as `Airport ** items`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't double the size until after you've made an assignment to the array where `counter == maxelements`, but `items[maxelements]` isn't valid -- only `maxelements - 1`.

If you move doublesize up above the assignment, things should work better.

Also, there's no reason to check if `total > maxElements`.  It's simply not necessary.

Comment: `doubleSize(items, maxElements, oldAmount);
            if (counter == maxElements - 1)
                doubleSize(items, maxElements, oldAmount);` Is this what you mean by moving it up above the assignment?

Comment: @Mark You can NEVER assign to items[current] when current==maxsize -- remember arrays start at 0, so a size=3 array has valid elements at 0, 1, and 2. You need to increase the size before you make that assignment.   So just move the if block above the assignment.   readline then if(current==maxsize){...} then items[current]=...

Comment: I understand now. The `AirportList` class does not have a copy constructor, destructor, and overloaded = operator as seen from above. Do you think that also could be causing the crashes?

Comment: Depends if you're making copies of it -- and if so what you do with them.   Something should probably be calling delete[] on items when it's destroyed, but that won't cause a crash, just a memory leak.   In general, if you dynamically allocate memory, you should have a destructor and either a custom copy constructor (or explicitly delete it with the "= delete;" option)

Comment: I have modified it to `if (counter == maxElements - 1) { double the size }`. Then readline then `items[counter] = Airport(cppstr);`. However, it still crashes. Could I still have misunderstood you?

Comment: it's more likely you have another problem.  run it in a debugger and see where it crashes.

Comment: This is weird. It crashes within the `for (int i = 0; i < oldAmount; i++)
            resized[i] = orig[i];` I'm not sure why.

Comment: Yeah that's weird.  Unrelated, there's no need to pass in any parameters to your doubleSize method.   It's a class method, so it already has access to them.

Comment: On the 10th iteration of that for loop, it crashes. Does that help with anything?

Comment: Why don't you post your updated code somewhere like gist.github.com.

Comment: Would you like me to post it on there? Also, ignore that crash earlier, I accidentally commented out the line `oldAmount = 10`, which is why it crashed there. It actually is crashing sometime within the for loop at the assignment `items[counter] = Airport(cppstr);`

Comment: It's the `-1` you added: `if (counter == maxElements - 1)`   Because you haven't filled the 10th spot (array index 9), when you try to copy from it in doubleSize, it tries to read uninitialized memory.   Get rid of the -1.

Comment: Ok, after removing it, doubleSize runs once and then the for loop continues, but sometime later it crashes at the same spot `items[counter] = Airport(cppstr);`. Also, after debugging it some more, the `maxElements` and `oldAmount` numbers are not changing. After the doubleSize runs once and changes these numbers, the for loop continues but the maxElements and oldAmount does not change. Shouldn't the numbers get updated since it's a class method?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was supposed to pass by reference for the `maxElements` and `oldAmount`. I thought I wouldn't need to pass by reference since its in the class method, is that weird? The numbers are now updating after the doubleSize runs. Everything works now.

Comment: yay.  It would make sense to pass them by reference into a non-class member function, since then it wouldn't have access to them.   but the fact that it's a class member means you dont' need to.  Glad you got everything working.

Comment: Thanks! The doubleSize function is a class member function, so why did I have to pass them by reference? I'm still a little bit confused.

Comment: Changing it to only pass in one parameter of the array works too `doubleSize(items);` and  `void doubleSize(Airport*& orig)`. I should use this instead right?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have an error with the copy constructor for the Airport class. You need to define a copy constructor for Airport (which does a deep copy of its data) and overload the assignment operator to use the new copy constructor. Otherwise, when you do `resized[i] = orig[i];`, you will do a shallow copy which ends up still pointing to data in the original (now deleted) Airport object.

Take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Comment: You don't think it could be related to the assignment into items[counter] when counter == maxelements?

Comment: My Airport class does not have a copy constructor since I don't have dynamic memory in that class. Do I still need a copy constructor?

Comment: @xaxxon missed that -- yes you definitely need to resize BEFORE calling items[counter] when counter == maxelements!